# /languages/ folder missing in default themes

Tags: translation, localization

I noticed that previous default themes used to have /languages/ folder which is now gone.

1. Is it now a good practice to not include the /languages/ folder when creating a custom theme? How do theme users translate it without this folder?
2. Where should MO files be uploaded to not have them overwritten when a theme is updated? If they are located in /wp-content/themes/theme-name/languages/ then after each theme update they'll be overwritten. Should they now be uploaded somewhere else?
3. Should plugins not create the /languages/ folder as well anymore?

Comment: did you find any answer in this topic? I'm also wondering what happened to these folders. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Themes and plugins on wordpress.org don't need a /language folder anymore. The translation is made via Glotpress on https://translate.wordpress.org/. Glotpress parses the files and you can start to translate. The translated .mo and .po files get automatic updates, if a translation string changes. They are stored in /wp-content/languages

If you don't host your Theme or plugin on wordpress.org you need a /language folder. More infos in the handbook: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/localization/